# Github auth works fine on jquery, but not react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain the difference to me? I have an example that works well, but it is with jquery

```
    $('#form').submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var username = 'example';
      var password = '123';
  
      let auth = btoa(username + ':' + password);
  
      fetch('https://api.github.com/user', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth,
        },
      }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       
    });
  });
```

and I want to make the same in react.js, but nothing works

```
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('example');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('123');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let auth = btoa(userName + ':' + password);
    fetch('https://api.github.com/user', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + auth,
      },
    }).then((response) => console.log(response));
  };
```

and that's error **GET https://api.github.com/user 401 (Unauthorized)**

Comment: Did you check the headers of tour outgoing request? Could you also show the code that's calling `handleSubmit`

Comment: Can you console.log userName and password to make sure that they exists?